# How to search on user_id in cb user lists?

Tags: user, search, community-builder

We want to use the id of users for our invoicing.
I've been able to display the user id field in lists and on the logout screen without any problems.

However, we also need to be able to search users based on the id to match the invoice back to the user (Don't ask me why we're not just using names!).

I've tried creating a custom html field, with content [user_id], but this field is not searchable.

I've tried adding [user_id] to a normal text field, and making that searchable, but nothing is returned from the search.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Jeff.  I definitely support the decision to uniquely identify your users by their `id` instead of their name -- this is a decision that will guarantee uniqueness.  Please continue to research and attempt to self-solve while you wait for support from this community.